# What is mean square root n in standard error (se)?

Tags: math, statistics

I can’t understand why we divide sd by √n, in search of standard errors in statistics.

I generated 1000 samples, then took the average from each sample, and got a new sample of averages.

using the central limit theorem..

but how is the related to this standard error (SE) of a statistic

Comment: Its all explained pretty well in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error Larger samples cluster more closely around the population mean, so as sample sizes increase, SE decreases. Dividing by sqrt(n) approximates this (larger N's mean smaller SE's).  From the same article: *Practically ... when trying to estimate ... a population mean, due to the factor 1 / n 1/{\sqrt {n}}, reducing the error on the estimate by a factor of two requires ... four times as many observations in the sample; reducing it by a factor of ten requires a hundred times as many observations*

Comment: I understand this perfectly, I do not understand the physical meaning of the formula

Comment: Maths is not my strongest suit either, but this is not a maths forum, its for programming problems. If you understand that as the sample size increases, the standard error decreases, you understand enough. And that is because larger samples give you better estimates of the population (true) mean. So that's all you really need to know unless you have some specific problem here.  Division by a sqrt(n) is merely a way to represent this (why? because it "works"). So it's meant to give you useful information, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calculating the sample mean, we draw n observations independently from the same population, add them up, and divide the sum by n to get the average.

So assuming the population has a variance of σ^2, then the sum of n independent observations from the same population will have a variance of n*σ^2. When we calculate the average, we will divide the sum by n, so the average will have a variance of (n*σ^2)/(n^2) = σ^2/n. We need to take the square root of the variance to find the standard deviation of the average, then we will get, σ/(√n). This is the reason why we have a √n when calculating the standard error of the sample mean - to approximate σ/(√n) we have for the standard deviation of the average.

I noticed the website, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error, mentioned by @topsail, also have a more formal proof of what I just explained. I put the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @frontjss, if you find the answer helpful, hope you would click and accept it, thanks! Let me know if you would like more explanations, happy to discuss more :)

Comment: why do we divide by n^2

Comment: @frontjss Because of the property of variance - suppose c is a constant and X is a random variable, then var(cX) = c^2 * var(X). Similarly, see 1/n as the constant, then var ((1/n)*X) = var(X)/(n^2). Hope this helps :)!

Comment: thank you))) I spent a lot of time to figure it out